# Typeahead js with dynamic multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

In typeahead js while using multiple data-sets (as seen here [typeahed multiple datasets](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets)) each category is sent as a separate parameter while initialising the typeahead. Is it possible to have dynamic categories from a single data source instead of multiple data sources.

```
 $('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
  highlight: true
},
{
  name: 'nba-teams',
  display: 'team',
  source: nbaTeams,
  templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
  }
},
{
  name: 'nhl-teams',
  display: 'team',
  source: nhlTeams,
  templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="league-name">NHL Teams</h3>'
  }
});
```

Here nba-teams and nhl-teams are sent as separate parameters to typeahead().IS there a way to send N datasets or specify the category the data belongs to like

```
    data = [
        { value: 'Chicago Blackhawks', data: { category: 'NHL' } },
        { value: 'Chicago Bulls', data: { category: 'NBA' } },
        { value: 'LA Galaxy', data: { category: 'MLS' } },
        { value: 'Seattle Founders', data: { category: 'MLS' } },
    ]
```

Comment: though its a bit old, did you try with [separator](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread-operator#spread-operator) for passing multiple objects as dynamic arguments?

Answer (score 0):

try using signature: [typeahead(options, [*datasets])](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadoptions-datasets); it worked for me with the [latest version](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js) combiined with Bloodhound object for `source` property.
* [ref-usage(internal project)](https://gitlab.com/rran/climate-portal/blob/master/templates/index.html#L920)